# python singleton code

Tags: python

Here is an example of singleton in python. One thing I don't understand is I think the _instance in class is always set to None, therefore the "if not cls._instance" should always true, therefore, there is no need for the if statement.

I know I am wrong, please help me where I missed.

```
class Singleton(object):
    _instance = None  # Keep instance reference 
    # why do this???? If do this, the "if not .." state follow is always true, right? 
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not cls._instance:
            cls._instance = object.__name__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instance
```

**Update**

My confusion is: Why the 2nd time you call Singleton(), the **_instance = None** is not triggered? Whereas it is triggered 1st call?

Comment: no, because `__new__` is also a class method. So first time instance doesn"t exist, and the other times, instance exists. That the way the singleton is implemented.

Answer (score 5):

`__new__` is a class method as well that supersedes the `__init__` method (you have control on the object which gets created at this level)

`_instance` is a class attribute, not an instance attribute. So it's visible/available in the `__new__` method *before* an instance is created.

So first time, the `cls._instance` argument is `None`, so `__new__` creates the instance and stores the result in the `_instance` class attribute of `cls` (which is your `Singleton` class)

It is not `None` the second time **because the reference of the instance has been stored**, so it returns the same `self._instance` object. In the process, `object.__new__` is only called once during the lifetime of the class.

This follows the *design pattern of the singleton*: create once, return the same object everytime.

note that this is incorrect:

```
cls._instance = object.__name__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
```

should be

```
cls._instance = object.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
```

Calling `object.__name__` makes no sense since it's a *string*. Small self-contained example derived from your code:

```
class Singleton(object):
    _instance = None  # Keep instance reference
    # why do this???? If do this, the if state follow is always false, right?
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not cls._instance:
            cls._instance = object.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
            print("creating")
        return cls._instance

a = Singleton()
b = Singleton()
print(a is b)
```

this code outputs:

```
creating
True
```

as you see, first time it's creating the object, then it's returning the same object the second time the object is created.

Comment: `object.__new__` surely. `object.__class__` is `type` and will try to create a new class, not an instance of Singleton

Comment: The 2nd time you call Singleton(), why "_instance = None" is not triggered? It is triggered in 1st call. Can you explain this part please?    @Jean-François Fabre

Comment: @Dunes ooops, it works by chance, not what op wants.. wrong fix.

Comment: @NicolasS.Xu because it is stored in `cls._instance`. `cls` is your current class.

Comment: Why "_instance = None" only run once? Why 2nd time you call Singleton(), the first line of this class is skipped?

Answer (score 2):

If `cls._instance` is `None`, then `not cls._instance` is `True`, not `False`.

Comment: your are right. My mistake. If it is always true, why need a "if" after always true value?

Comment: Because you update `cls._instance` in the process, so that the next time around, `cls._instance` is no longer `None`, and `not cls._instance` is no longer `True`.

Comment: You said " so that the next time around, cls._instance is no longer None" . This part I don't understand. Why? I think every time, the _instance is set to None. Is it so?

Comment: @NicolasS.Xu No. `_instance` is a class attribute, not an instance attribute.

Comment: @DeepSpace So class attribute can only be set once?

Comment: @NicolasS.Xu. The values of class attributes are shared between all instances, because they are stored on the ***class-object*** rather than the ***instance-object***. Since all instances have the *same class*, they will all see the same class attribute values.